# Find Date in Column and Paste to Multiple Adjacent Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a calendar that I'm trying to have populate with userform data in the first blank "appointment slot" upon a button click. An Appointment slot for the date 12/1 would be the cell ranges from E2:J3 then the next appointment slot for the same date is K2:P3 and so on and so forth.

What I'm trying to get it to do is for the next open appointment slot to be filled with the userform data on click of a button.

I.E; Once button is clicked, if date is 12/1 then groupname.text would paste to E2, groupsize.text would paste in F2, lessontime.text would paste in E3...etc. If there's already an appointment in E2:J3 then it would paste in the next apoointment slot; K2 for groupname.text, etc.

It must be based on the date in column D, which the code below can find, but I can't figure out how to use LastRow to loop through the appointment slots to find a blank one. Not to mention how to paste in several different cells and not just ones in the same row.

Help?

[image]

```
If IsDate(DT.Text) Then
Dim thedate As Date
thedate = CDate(DT.Text)
Dim themonth As String
themonth = Format(thedate, "mmm") 'this bit of code is used for another sheet as well

'a bunch of other code for a different task that's happening at the same time.


Dim rng1 As Range
Dim dateStr As String
Dim dateToFind As Date
Dim foundDate As Range
dim cal as worksheet
dim nxtappointment as long

cal = thisworkbook.sheets("calendar")
nxtappointment '= ? this would be the lastrow


dateStr = Format(thedate, ddmm)


dateToFind = DateValue(DT.Text)


Set rng1 = Sheets("Calendar").Range(Cells(4, 1), _
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

Set foundDate = rng1.Find(What:=dateToFind, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)


If Not foundDate Is Nothing Then
cal.range(E & nxtappointment).value = groupname.text
'etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there's to things:

- Find the first blank slot for an appointment. I usually do something like this. Adapt the column and possibly the offset from last non-empty cell accordingly. For a start this should be good.

```vb
    Function FindEmptySlotRow(wks As Worksheet) As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim columnToSearch As Integer
        columnToSearch = 2 'replace with column index which is always filled for an appointment.
        Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
        'Search from the bottom of the file in case we have a blank slot in between
        For i = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If wks.Cells(i, columnToSearch).Value <> vbNullString Then
                'we've got a non-empty cell. We just need to know if it's the first or second row of an appoitment slot.
                Dim isFirstRowOfAppointment As Boolean
                isFirstRowOfAppointment = i Mod 2 = 0 'Your first appointment rows appear to be in odd even rows
                If isFirstRowOfAppointment Then
                    firstEmptyRow = i + 2 '+2 rows - since we found the non-empty cell in first appointment row
                Else
                    firstEmptyRow = i + 1 '+1 row - since we found the non-empty cell in second appointment row
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        FindEmptySlotRow = firstEmptyRow
    End Function
```

- Paste the data. I would do something reusable based on the empty row/cell I find in the previous function. Something in the likes of:

```vb
'fill appointment details based on top left cell of appointment
Sub PasteAppointmentData(topLeftAppointmentCell As Range)
    'define ranges based on starting cell - EXAMPLE VALUES - adapt to your needs
    Dim appointmentNameCell As Range
    Dim appointmentTypeCell As Range

    appointmentNameCell = topLeftAppointmentCell
    appointmentTypeCell = topLeftAppointmentCell.Offset(0, 1)

    'define values you want to store and get them from the form - EXAMPLE VALUES - adapt to your needs
    Dim appointmentName As String
    Dim appointmentType As String

    appointmentName = txtboxName.Text
    appointmentType = textboxType.Text

    'store values in respective ranges
    appointmentNameCell.Value = appointmentName
    appointmentTypeCell.Value = appointmentType

End Sub
```

**REMARK**:
Not sure if I understand correctly, but If you're planning to store multiple appointments for the same day in the same row, I advise against this. Just like I would advise against using 2 rows per appointment. I would suggest a database-like approach. One row per record/appointment with columns that contain appointment properties. That proves beneficial if you want to make some edits/reporting later. Also, it makes your code much easier to write (e.g. no problem of checking for first or second row of appointment anymore).

Hope this helps you get an idea on how to solve this.